# PyQt6 - Не реагирует на нажатия кнопок-стрелок

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6, keypressevent

Хотел сделать переход на комбинации `Ctrl + Alt + <-` `Ctrl + Alt + ->`, но увы, никак не хотят обрабатываться нажатия кнопок стрелок.

На виджете 2 `QPushButton`, 1 `QLabel` и 1 `QLineEdit`

В будущем нужно будет перехватывать комбинации из ОС, пока приложение работает в фоне или не является активным окном

Как решить проблему с перехватом событий кнопок стрелок (`Qt.Key.Key_Left`, и тп)? 
Другие события нажатий отрабатывают корректно (пример с `ESC`)

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
        modifiers = event.modifiers()
        key = event.key()
        print(modifiers, key)
        print(event.text())

        if key == Qt.Key.Key_Escape.value:
            self.slot_change_counter_name_rejected()


        if modifiers == (
                Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier | Qt.KeyboardModifier.AltModifier
        ):
            print('here')
            if key == Qt.Key.Key_Left.value:
                self.slot_prev_counter()

            elif key == Qt.Key.Key_Right.value:
                self.slot_next_counter()

        if key == Qt.Key.Key_Left.value:
            self.slot_prev_counter()

        elif key == Qt.Key.Key_Right.value:
            self.slot_next_counter()
```

---

UPD:

Идея с шоркатами помогла в плане работы при активном окне. Теперь остается вопрос с глобальными событиями нажатий.

```
        btn_left.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+Left"))
        btn_left.setEnabled(True)

        btn_right.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+Right"))
        btn_right.setEnabled(True)
```

---

UPD 2:

В конце `__init__` метода виджета добавил метод, в котором описал глобальные сочетания кнопок. Локальные комбинации остались в `keyPressEvent`. Это полностью решило проблему.

````
    def __init__():
        .....
        self._global_keyPressEvent()

    def _global_keyPressEvent(self):
        keyboard.add_hotkey("Ctrl + Alt + Left", self.slot_prev_counter, suppress=True)
        keyboard.add_hotkey("Ctrl + Alt + Right", self.slot_next_counter, suppress=True)

        keyboard.add_hotkey("Ctrl + plus", self.slot_counter_increase, suppress=True)
        keyboard.add_hotkey("Ctrl + -", self.slot_counter_decrease, suppress=True)
    ```
````

Comment: Почему бы самим кнопкам не указать комбинацию?

Comment: В плане? Чем это мне поможет?

Comment: А разве кнопки не выполняют эту же роль? Переключают? Можно на кнопки повесить действие перехода и комбинации

Comment: Если на виджет ловить, тогда посмотрите на https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setShortcutEnabled, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabShortcut и ловите событие QEvent::Shortcut (но я не уверен каким обработчиком ловить событие, мб сойдет и keyPressEvent)

Comment: да, кнопки делают тоже самое, но комбинации - это альтернатива без мыши

Comment: вообще, в потом нужно будет перехватывать кобминации из ОС, когда приложение будет работать в фоне. Возможно тогда шорткаты не помогут, но спасибо, пока посмотрю что можно сделать с ними

Comment: Вот идея с кнопками https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/39e6090e6a41c7ebe5982c027ffd7a248e858fa8/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/buttons_setShortcut.py для PyQt6 нужно только поменять название модуля. Для ловли из ОС не уверен, что Qt умеет (возможно, мои знания устарели, подправьте если уже есть), но можно использовать модуль `keyboard`, но понадобится его в отдельном потоке запускать, пример использования модуля: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/210b6bc17de224ce054318586125a283df10b8de/pyautogui__keyboard__examples/hotkey__hello_world.py

Comment: @gil9red если оформите как ответ, поставлю как правильный ответ

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример,
который демонстрирует проблему.

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.keymap = {}
        for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
            if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
                self.keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

        self.modmap = {
            Qt.ControlModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
            Qt.AltModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
            Qt.ShiftModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
            Qt.MetaModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
            Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
            Qt.KeypadModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
        }

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in self.modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = self.keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.keyevent_to_string(event))
        self.label.setText(self.keyevent_to_string(event))

        if self.keyevent_to_string(event) == "Control+Q":
            self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = Window()
    w.resize(200, 100)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если окно не является активным, вам понадобится дополнительная библиотека,
например `keyboard`.

Comment: Ваш пример не дает ответа на вопрос. Проблема была со стрелками. Проблема решена частично шоткатами. Полностью keyboard ом, для которого нет примера. Извините

Comment: Но спасибо за попытку

Comment: @ZaArs. ну решена так  решена. Я давал некоторые ответы связанные с `keyboard` и вы можете найти их на этом ресурсе.